# Toggle Button & Date Range Picker not show in Codigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use the date range picker & toggle button as follows in my codigniter project :

### Expected Result

Expected Result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3KNN.png)

### Generated out

But the code outs following view

Generated out (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogKzq.png)

Outed result can't show the date range picker & toggle button. What may be goinh wrong ? Can anyone help ?

I tried the following code to do this :

```
`<script src="<?= base_url() ?>public/dist/js/issues.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>public/plugins/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>`

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Survey Inventory</h3>

                <div class="box-tools pull-right">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" style="font-size: 16px;" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>

                </div>
                <!-- /.box-tools -->
            </div>

            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <?= form_open('survey/regSurvey') ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">


                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-warning">
                                <div class="panel-heading">Please select these before adding any book</div>
                                <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 5px;">
                                    <div class="col-md-4" id="survey_date">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="sldate">Survey Date *</label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="text" name="date" value="" readonly style="cursor: pointer" class="form-control input-tip" id="date" required="required" data-original-title="" title="" data-bv-field="date">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="survey_date" id="survey_date" value="<?= date('Y-m-d') ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_date" id="cancel_date" value="<?= date('Y-m-d') ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4" style="display: none" id="cancel_date">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="cancel_date">Cancel Date </label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="text" name="cancel_date" value="<?= date('Y-m-d') ?>" readonly style="cursor: pointer" class="form-control input-tip datepicker" id="cancel_date" required="required" data-original-title="" title="" data-bv-field="date">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Type</label>
                                            <div class="switch-toggle switch-ios">
                                                <input id="surveyed" class="type" name="type" type="radio" value="surveyed" checked>
                                                <label for="surveyed" onclick="">Survey</label>
                                                <input id="canceled" class="type" name="type" value="canceled" type="radio">
                                                <label for="canceled" onclick="">Cancel</label>
                                                <a></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12" id="sticker">
                            <div class="well well-sm">
                                <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0;">
                                    <div class="input-group wide-tip">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
                                            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-barcode addIcon"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php echo form_input('add_item', '', 'class="form-control input-lg" id="add_item" placeholder="' . "Add Books to Survey List" . '"'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="control-group table-group">
                                <label class="table-label">Surveyed / Canceled Books *</label>

                                <div class="controls table-controls">
                                    <table id="blTable" class="table items table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover sortable_table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="col-md-3">Book Name</th>
                                                <th class="col-md-3">Book no</th>
                                                <th class="col-md-3">ISBN</th>
                                                <th class="col-md-1" id="tdQty">Quantity</th>

                                                <th style="width: 30px !important; text-align: center;">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);"></i>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody></tbody>
                                        <tfoot></tfoot>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group"><input type="submit" name="add_survey" value="Submit" id="add_survey" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 6px 15px; margin:15px 0;">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="reset" tabindex="-1">Reset</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?= form_close() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code for date range picker in the issues.js as follows :

```
$(function () {
    $('#date').daterangepicker(
        {
            locale: {
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            },
            ranges: {
                'One Week': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'w')],
                'Two Weeks': [moment(), moment().add(2, 'w')],
                'Three Weeks': [moment(), moment().add(3, 'w')],
                'One Month': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'M')]
            },
            minDate: moment(),
            startDate: moment(), endDate: moment().add(7, 'days')
        },
        function (start, end) {
            console.log(start);
            $('#issued_date').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            $('#receive_date').val(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Did you include the JavaScript files for the Date Range Picker library and initialize it? See the first two code blocks on the page here, under 'Getting Started': https://www.daterangepicker.com/ Second code block should be `$('input[name="date"]').daterangepicker();` in your case. (I don't know what library you're using for the toggle button, so I can't point you to any documentation on that.)

Comment: @ 
Marleen.  I included the JavaScript files for the Date Range Picker library and initialized it. And used toggle-switch library for the toggle button.

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in the console? And could you show your header file, or the part where you're including all of your JavaScript libraries and also the part where you're doing the initialisation? Hard to troubleshoot without seeing all of the code. :)

Comment: looks like missing css links(library) to me... everything is there (If I read the images  correctly), just not formatted the way you expect...

Comment: @Marleen
 . No any error messages in the console. javascript used for date range picker is added to the above code. pls. see on it. This code placed in the issues.js file

Comment: If I paste the code you've provided into a blank HTML template inside a blank CI 4 installation, and add the JS/CSS CDN links for the date range picker, the picker only works when I change the script src for `issues.js` to `<script src="<?= base_url() ?>/dist/js/issues.js"></script>`. If I run the application via `php spark serve` (as per CI 4 documentation) this does not give a 404 error in the console for the `issues.js` file, even though it apparently can't find it. Does changing the script src solve your problem?